# Demonstrating that proposed cutoff score is non optimal

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, roc, diagnostic, diagnosis

I have a small data set with a test score and classification (positive or negative diagnosis). There is already clinical evidence that the cut point suggested by the test manufacturer produces too many false positives when the test is used on the target population. How do I proceed if I want to accumulate statistical evidence that the "official" cut point should be adjusted?

I have the classification matrix, plus various indicators of classification quality (sensitivity, specificity, ROC AUC, etc.) when using the official cut point  and the empirically determined cut point (found by applying the R function [cutpointr:](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cutpointr/vignettes/cutpointr.html) to my sample). I also have from the test documentation the size of the sample used to normalize the test, as well as the mean and sd.

Comment: In effect you have two points on the ROC curve.  Why not just show the curve, highlight the two points and then explain why you think the one you prefer is better

Comment: To fully answer this question, you need to add the "cost" information, i.e. determine how much false positives cost in terms of they actions they trigger, and then how much damage results from missing some true positives.  Then you combine that information with your confusion matrix, and optimize.